# Stuck on ACIII at some type of gate to a subway or train station?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

I am stuck at the point where you have to sneak by the guards in some underground modern train station or subway.  She says to sneak by and the hide.  I keep being push by the guards/ticket takers and the alerting the policemen on the other side. How do I proceed ?

Answer (score 2):

I take it you're talking about the subway station in Brazil. Generally, you need to proceed stealthily, i. e., blend in with the people standing around and move from group to group.

Here's a rough outline of the mission, from the beginning to the end:

- Follow the crowd in the subway and watch the cutscene.
- Head for the door with the green light above it and stealthily proceed through the garden area. There are stairs with a kissing couple on it – exit the outdoor area here and blend in with the crowd.
- Move from group to group and proceed through the bathroom to avoid the checkpoint. After exiting on the other side, blend in again and head toward the VIP section. There should be a doorway soon that leads to a stairwell.
- Upstairs there's a corridor with people and a guard. Avoid him by blending in with one of the groups. Enter the room at the end and walk along the catwalk to the other side. Proceed to the next room for a cutscene.
- Ignore security when the chase is on.
- After combat, follow the METRO signs to escape.